# How do I declare a string without assigning a value in C++?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, int, cin

I know that for an integer, you can use:

```
int value;
```

I tried:

```
string str;
```

but Visual C++ gave me an error. How do I declare it without assigning a value, then using `cin >> str` later on to assign it?

Comment: Modify this question to include the actual error message - that information is the compiler trying to help you; at least give us that benefit too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
 std::string str;
 return 0;
}
```

Check this info on [Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cb46ksf(VS.80).aspx) by MSDN

Comment: I can also write "using namespace std; string str;" right? I read it here while googling (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html) but I thought since I already wrote "using namespace std;" below the "#include <iostream>" I did not have to re-write it.

Comment: Also, if you find you're using std::string in your code a lot, `using std::string;` will help.

Comment: In general it's recommended to not use `using namespace std;` but to just pull in the parts of the std namespace that you'll actually use: `using std::string; using std::cout; using std::endl;`, for instance.

Comment: Fabian, you are right of course, you don't have to rewrite it

Comment: Why won't this work? #include <iostring>
#include <string>

int main() {
 std::string str;
 cout << "Hi";
 cin.get();
}

Comment: @Fabian, because it should be std::cout, std::cin

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

int main() {
    string str;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
  string str;
  cout << "Enter a string: ";
  cin >> str;
  cout << "You entered: " << str;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between iostring and iostream?

Comment: that'd be a typo. :P  Thanks!